# How to make gap in chart.js graph?

Tags: chart.js

This is the required graph I need to create. Can anyone tell me how can I create that gap between y-axis and first label of x-axis (January)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish that by creating a chart plugin, like so ...

```
Chart.plugins.register({
    afterUpdate: function(chart) {
        var dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[0];
        var offset = 27;
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
            var model = dataset._meta[0].data[i]._model;
            model.x += offset;
            model.controlPointNextX += offset;
            model.controlPointPreviousX += offset;
        }
    }
});
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
// register plugin
Chart.plugins.register({
    afterUpdate: function(chart) {
        var dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[0];
        var offset = 27; //set that suits the best
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
            var model = dataset._meta[0].data[i]._model;
            model.x += offset;
            model.controlPointNextX += offset;
            model.controlPointPreviousX += offset;
        }
    }
});

// generate chart
var ctx = document.querySelector('#canvas').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Line Chart',
            data: [10, 20, 18, 16, 19, 22],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192, 0.4)',
            borderColor: '#4bc0c0',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'black',
            tension: 0,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    offsetGridLines: true,
                    display: false
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="340" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man..but it shifted the labels on x-axis but it didn't shift the graph.My graph still touches the y axis.

Comment: @manthanbaranwal  what you mean by *didn't shift the graph*? you can clearly see on the given demo that the graph has shifted, not the labels.

Comment: Is the implementation would be same if i am using ng2-charts??

Comment: @manthanbaranwal yes, the basic implementation would be the same

Comment: actually the problem that i m stiil facing is my first point of graph is still on y-axis.You got it now? I can't show you image here.

Comment: @manthanbaranwal isn't the chart given in the demo looks right to you? if yes then, you may have some other implementation issues

Comment: Chart is demo is right.But your solution is not working for me. I might need little more help from u.How can i contact you?

Comment: here is the link of plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/IgFw6pwxXAX7ypO95XpT?p=catalogue

Answer (score 2):

You can create a gap by specifying the min and max values of the scale.

In your case, you have **X** as a **time scale** and **Y** as a **linear scale**. Therefore each will have its own additional options.

If you determine the min and max of your data then you can add an offset to your scale range. For example [min - 123, max + 123] considering that the offset is 123.

I created bellow an Angular component which uses Chart.js. Angular component because this seems to be the requirement. Also the `angular` tag was placed before the question was edited. If the Angular component is not required then the important logic is found inside `createChart()` and most of the code is related to `Chart.js` and little to Angular.

Note that the following code is written in `TypeScript` as this is the recommended way of writing Angular apps.

**Dependencies**

- **Graph.js:** npm install --save chart.js
- **Graph.js typings:** typings install --save --global dt~chartjs
- **Moment:** npm install --save moment

**Chart data model**

Chart data set is modeled as such:

```
export interface GraphDataSet {
  label: string;
  data: { x: any, y: any }[];
}
```

Where `label` is the label which describes this data set.

`data` is the array of x-y pairs that describe the position of X and Y axis.

Note that one chart can have multiple data sets. This model corresponds to one data set. Therefore the chart component will receive an array of data set models.

**Component**

```
import {AfterViewChecked, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import 'chart.js';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import {GraphDataSet} from './GraphDataSet';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'graph-line',
  template: `<canvas #canvas [width]="width" [height]="height"></canvas>`
})
export class GraphLineComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  private _canvas: ElementRef;
  private _dataSets: GraphDataSet[];
  private _chart: Chart;

  @Input()
  width: number;

  @Input()
  height: number;

  @Input()
  public dataSets: GraphDataSet[];

  @ViewChild('canvas')
  public canvas: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.canvas !== this._canvas || this.dataSets !== this._dataSets) {
      this._canvas = this.canvas;
      this._dataSets = this.dataSets;
      setTimeout(() => this.createChart(), 0);
    }
  }

  private createChart() {

    const ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

    // create background linear gradient (top-to-bottom)
    const backgroundGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(this.width / 2, 0, this.width / 2, this.height);
    backgroundGradient.addColorStop(0, '#5ebb95');
    backgroundGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');

    // create default settings that can be used to style the dataset
    const defaultDataSetSettings = {
      backgroundColor: backgroundGradient,
      borderColor: '#5ebb95',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#5ebb95',
      tension: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 7,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 10
    };

    const data = {
      datasets: this.dataSets.map(dataSet => Object.assign({}, defaultDataSetSettings, dataSet))
    };

    const xMin = this.getXMin(this.dataSets);
    const xMax = this.getXMax(this.dataSets);
    const timeXMin = xMin.subtract(1, 'months');
    const timeXMax = xMax.add(1, 'months');

    this._chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            title: (item, chartData) => item.map(i => chartData.datasets[i.datasetIndex].label),
            label: (item, chartData) => item.yLabel + ' on ' + moment(item.xLabel).format('LL')
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            position: 'bottom',
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            time: {
              displayFormats: {
                month: 'MMM'
              },
              unit: 'month',
              min: timeXMin,
              max: timeXMax
            },
            ticks: {
              callback: (value, index, values) => {
                const date = values[index];
                console.log(date.diff(xMin, 'months'));
                return date.diff(xMin, 'days') <= 0 || date.diff(xMax, 'days') >= 0 ? null : value;
              }
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left',
            gridLines: {
              borderDash: [10, 10],
              zeroLineWidth: 0
            },
            ticks: {
              min: 0,
              fixedStepSize: 200,
              callback: (value) => value === 0 ? null : value
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private getXMin(dataSets: GraphDataSet[]) {
    let min: Date = null;

    dataSets.forEach(dataSet => {
      dataSet.data.forEach(data => {
        if (!min || data.x < min) {
          min = data.x;
        }
      });
    });

    return moment(min);
  }

  private getXMax(dataSets: GraphDataSet[]) {
    let max: Date = null;

    dataSets.forEach(dataSet => {
      dataSet.data.forEach(data => {
        if (!max || data.x > max) {
          max = data.x;
        }
      });
    });

    return moment(max);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<graph-line [dataSets]="dataSets" [width]="500" [height]="300"></graph-line>
```

**Data**

```
this.dataSets = [
  {
    label: 'My Monthly Report',
    data: [
      {x: Date.parse('2017-01-10'), y: 500},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-02-15'), y: 700},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-03-10'), y: 600},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-04-20'), y: 590},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-05-30'), y: 610},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-06-25'), y: 800}
    ]
  }
];
```

### Explanation

**Explanation :: X Axis**

```
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        position: 'bottom',
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM'
          },
          unit: 'month',
          min: timeXMin,
          max: timeXMax
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: (value, index, values) => {
            const date = values[index];
            console.log(date.diff(xMin, 'months'));
            return date.diff(xMin, 'days') <= 0 || date.diff(xMax, 'days') >= 0 ? null : value;
          }
        }
      }],
```

This is a time axis which has the range determined by `timeXMin` and `timeXMax`. These are computed by finding the min and max of all data sets. Then an offset of one month is added like so `xMin.subtract(1, 'months')` and `xMax.add(1, 'months')` respectively.

`time.displayFormats.month` will display months as labels.

`time.unit: 'month'` will split the scale into months, then each of the unit will be formated as label using `time.displayFormats.month`.

`ticks.callback` is used to remove the labels for time units that are outside of `[xMin, xMax]` which is the min and max of all data sets.

**Explanation :: Y Axis**

```
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
        gridLines: {
          borderDash: [10, 10],
          zeroLineWidth: 0
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          fixedStepSize: 200,
          callback: (value) => value === 0 ? null : value
        }
      }]
```

This is a linear scale.

`gridLines.borderDash` creates dash lines for each tick on the linear scale.

`ticks.min: 0` specify that the scale will start at zero.

`ticks.fixedStepSize: 200` specify that each scale tick will have a step of 200.

`ticks.callback` remove the label for 0 value.

**Explanation :: Component lifecycle**

Component has `width` and `height` inputs in order to set the size of the `<canvas>` which is the only element inside its template.

Another input is `dataSets` which is the actual data that is passed to `Chart.js`.

The component has `ngAfterViewChecked()` hook, which means that can check for changes like, if any input has changed or if the `<canvas>` element has changed for some reason. If we see that some of the inputs have changed then we create the chart like this `setTimeout(() => this.createChart(), 0);`. `setTimeout()` is used because at this time we cannot change any parameters, and to be safe, the processing is done on a separate call stack.

**Explanation :: Data**

```
this.dataSets = [
  {
    label: 'My Monthly Report',
    data: [
      {x: Date.parse('2017-01-10'), y: 500},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-02-15'), y: 700},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-03-10'), y: 600},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-04-20'), y: 590},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-05-30'), y: 610},
      {x: Date.parse('2017-06-25'), y: 800}
    ]
  }
];
```

Because `X` is a `linear scale` and `Y` is a `time scale`, data is formatted as `{ x, y }`. `x` is a date type and `y` is a number. `x` and `y` properties are recognized by `Chart.js` and assigned to `X` and `Y` scales respectively.

**Explanation :: Dataset Settings**

```
const ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

// create background linear gradient (top-to-bottom)
const backgroundGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(this.width / 2, 0, this.width / 2, this.height);
backgroundGradient.addColorStop(0, '#5ebb95');
backgroundGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');

// create default settings that can be used to style the dataset
const defaultDataSetSettings = {
  backgroundColor: backgroundGradient,
  borderColor: '#5ebb95',
  borderWidth: 1,
  pointBackgroundColor: '#5ebb95',
  tension: 0,
  pointBorderWidth: 7,
  pointHoverBorderWidth: 10
};

const data = {
  datasets: this.dataSets.map(dataSet => Object.assign({}, defaultDataSetSettings, dataSet))
};
```

The purpose of this code is to create the default settings that can be associated with a data set. The default data set settings are extended with the user defined ones like `datasets: this.dataSets.map(dataSet => Object.assign({}, defaultDataSetSettings, dataSet))`.

In the design the `backgroundColor` is a gradient, therefore a gradient which transition from top-to-bottom is created using the canvas context `ctx.createLinearGradient(...)`.